# What's the fastest way to determine all the subgroups of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Question is as in title.

I know that all of the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ (under addition) must be cyclic, and I could find them by finding the generating groups for each element of $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ - but surely there is a quicker way?

Would appreciate any help,

Jack

Comment: There is a theorem which says any cyclic group of order n has a unique subgroup of each order dividing n. So for $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$, it's divisors are 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24 so there are exactly 8 subgroups, all cyclic with these orders.

Comment: Thanks - but what if I actually wanted to find these subgroups?

Comment: let's you want to find a generator of the subgroup of order 6. Then the generator is 24/6 = 4 and so the subgroup $\{0,4,8,12,16,20 \}$ is precisely the subgroup

Answer (score 3):

In a cyclic group we know that we have only one group of order $n$, for each n which divides the order of the group.
$24 = 3\cdot2^3$ so we know that we have $8$ subgroups.

All the subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic, so all the subgroups are isomorphic to:
$\mathbb{Z_2},\mathbb{Z_3},\mathbb{Z_4},\mathbb{Z_6},\mathbb{Z_8},\mathbb{Z_{12}},\mathbb{Z_{24}}$.

If you want to know explicitely the elements of the subgroups you must find a generator for the subgroup:

Let's consider $\mathbb{Z_2}$: the order of the group is $2$ so the generator is $\frac{24}{2}=12.$ So the subgroup is ${\{0,12\}}$.

We do the same for the others:

$\mathbb{Z_3}$: Generator = $8$ so the subgroup is $\{0,8,16\}$

$\mathbb{Z_4}$: Generator = $6$ so the subgroup is $\{0,6,12,18\}$

$\mathbb{Z_6}$: Generator = $4$ so the subgroup is $\{0,4,8,12,16,20\}$

$\mathbb{Z_8}$: Generator = $3$ so the subgroup is $\{0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21\}$

$\mathbb{Z_{12}}$: Generator = $2$ so the subgroup is $\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22\}$

Comment: This has already been said in the comments. How about explicitly listing these groups?

Comment: Done. You are in a cyclic group and all the subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic. So they are easy to find.

Comment: No, those are not the required subgroups, those are *isomorphic* to the required subgroups.

Comment: Oh, so you want to find all the elements of the subgroups.. I'll do it.

Comment: Done, if you have other questions ask for further infos.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alberto. Although I haven't yet learnt what isomorphic means? I've googled it and sort of understand it - yet I don't understand how you deduced "so all subgroups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2},\mathbb{Z_3},\mathbb{Z_4},\mathbb{Z_6},\mathbb{Z_8},\mathbb{Z_{12}},\mathbb{Z_{24}}$"?

Comment: Two groups are isomorphic if you can create an isomorphism between them. You know that an omomorphism is injective if $o(x)=o(f(x))$ where 'o' means order. So, if you want a concrete example, you can create an isomorphism between the subgroup you considered, ${\{0,12\}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_2}$ by sending the generator of the first, $12$, in the generator of the second, 1. So you have only one isomorphism between those subgroups and you see that $12$, which has order 2, is sent in 1, which has order 2 too in $\mathbb{Z_2}$

Answer (score 3):

What is important has already been said in comments and other answers: for each $d \mid n$, there is a single subgroup of order $d$ in $\Bbb Z_n$, and it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_d$. It can be explicitly described as

$$\left\{ \widehat {\frac {kn} d} \Bigg| 0 \le k \le d-1 \right\} .$$